# While and if statement in php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($row['status'] == "Opened") {
            $test = "1";
        } else {
            $test = "0";
        }
    }
}
echo $test;
```

The problem occurs when there are multiple entries in the database and one of those entries does not have status = "Opened" therefore `$test` returns "0". I am trying to accomplish that if ANY of the entries have status = "Opened", `$test` will return "1".

Comment: You should not be doing this with a loop in php.  You should be doing this with a single query in the database.

Comment: That will depend on what the query is for this, that you didn't post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to directly select the data you need from the database instead of filtering it out with PHP.

```
SELECT id, message, etc FROM tickets WHERE status = 'Opened'
// if it fetches data, you have open tickets and have directly access to the data of the open tickets.

SELECT count(*) AS total FROM tickets WHERE status = 'Opened'
// the result of this is a number of the total amount of opened tickets, perhaps better for this specific use.
```

But on the subject on how to fix your loop you can do the following:

```
$open = false;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row['status'] == "Opened") {
        $open = true;
        break;
    } 
}
```

As this will quit the while loop, setting `$open` for futher use:

```
if($open){
  // do your stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT `status` FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 'Opened'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$test = (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

No need to fetch, it will be faster too.

Comment: Upon testing it only returns the value "0".

Comment: Double check your table because this code is correct